# Multiple arguments from DjangoTemplateLanguage to re_path()

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose there's an urlpattern as such :

```
re_path('^(app){3}/$', views.apple, name='apple'),
```

My understanding is that
if I want to use a hyperlink of this in templates,  I should do as such:

```
<a href="{% url 'apple' 'app' 'app' 'app' %}">apple</a>
```

But what if I wanted to make this pattern?

```
re_path('^(app){100}/$', views.apple, name='apple'),
```

Is there a better way than spamming arguments?

Comment: Your actual path, is it the same argument/string repeated ("app") or is it just a repeating pattern? How is this "list" of arguments generated? What do the arguments represent?

Comment: I don't have any specific intention right now. As stupid as it may sound, I'm just curious technically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really did have 100 arguments that you needed to generate a url from, you'd be better doing so in your view as there is not a convenient way of doing so in the template tag

```
context['url_with_100_args'] = reverse('apple', args=['app' for _ in range(100)]))
```

Then pass this to your template

```
<a href="{{ url_with_100_args }}">apple</a>
```